# How to keep running a python priority queue every second?

Tags: python, console, priority-queue

I have to create a priority queue that has to be running every second and storing some values "string" on a file.  The thing is that nobody has even told me what kind of priority put per each value I add in the queue ?¿

I have to create a python module that among other things have to run a priority every second and store values that are in it in a file?

The funny thing is that those values are coming from what you type in the console:

```
>>> python consumer.py "value to store in the queue"
```

Could anyone advise me on how to do this??

Regards

Comment: I don´t really see the point on keep running the queue every second knowing that the values are coming from the console ?    is it that I might have to run something in parallel?

Comment: Are you sure that it needs to be a priority queue? Does the user enter some text that indicates what the priority is? If not, then likely all you need is a FIFO queue.